# Can Jsoup clean up elements based on its class?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to try to clean up pretty much all the html from a document but white list a **span** tag with a **specific class**.

I've got this, but obviously this ends allowing all spans with attr class

```
String html = "<p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor<br /> sit amet</strong></p>"+
"<span class=\"killme\">Aenean</span> quam sem" +
"<span class=\"whitelistme\">lacinia molestie</span> nibh mattis ";

String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, 
                     Whitelist.none()
                     .addTags("span")
                     .addAttributes("span", "class"));
```

Is there a way to clean all html except the **<span class="whitelistme">** ?

so my end result will be

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Aenean quam sem
<span class="whitelistme">lacinia molestie</span> nibh mattis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking to Jsoup solution, **you can try following steps, but it is hardcode:**

1. Extract all value elements from text to a list.
2. Extract all values from span elements to another list.
3. Modify text values with appended mark, like OMG_value.
4. Remove all html tags from text.
5. Iterate and replace all OMG_values with value from saved list.

**If you find another solution - stick to it.** This is a hardcode savior from your cruel CEO.

Comment: Thanks D1e, indeed this will make the trick, but as you mention this is hardcoded. I was expecting something along the lines the jquery selector way, something like .clean(".whitelistme")..

Comment: You can also try tweaking some source code, if it is legal of course.
Use clean() method as an example to implement your own method like clean(EnumHtml.Tag... excludes).

Comment: yep, it's on public git, I might give it a try to that one. bTW, I'll give you the credit on this one. Thanks